# Blur UILable text line by line

Tags: ios, swift, blur, uiblureffect

I want to blur the text of my `UILabel` line by line. Currently I am applying a `UIBlurEffect` onto the `UILabel` but this simply blurs the whole view (obviously).

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

But I want to make sure, that the user can recognize the lines and even the rough structure of the text like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Blurr effect's apply to the whole view. There are a few third party libraries you can use for a gaussian blurr (the type of blur used in `UIBlurEffect`) that will give you more control over the blur radius (the amount of blur). A good third party library for this would be `GPUImage`. If you want to stick with apple's classes, you can try setting the `.alpha` property of `UIVisualEffectView` slightly less than 1 to weaken the effect of the blur. I'd try starting at around `.9` and test from there as much more than this and the blur is hardly noticeable.

Comment: Also I will note changing the alpha value of a `UIVisualEffectView` will give a warning (can't remember whether it was a debug console warning or an xcode warning) saying changing this property is not recommended. This is some what of a hack I learned to dim the very strong blur of `UIBlurEffect`.

Comment: I know that the UIBlurEffect is for the whole view. Thanks for the link to GPUImage library. It seems to be what I want but is it available for rows of text? I already tried to adjust the alpha but it was neither working well nor is it encouraged by Apple to change it AFAIK.

Comment: It is kind of hard to tell what you mean by rows of text. Do you have maybe an image of your desired effect? Is your text underlined and you want the underlines in focus and only text blurred? And no its not. In fact with `GPUImage` i believe you have to pass in a `UIImage`. So you have to take a CGContextual image of your view that you want blurred. A little more work but a lot more customization over your blur or other filters it comes with.

Comment: I've added a picture to clarify what I am after.

Comment: I think using `GPUImage` and setting a realtively small blur radius, i.e. 1-2 pixels should give you the effect you are after. The class name is `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` in the library.